# C# 8 switch case no castea los Dictionary<TKey,TValue> con una interfaz

Tags: c#, interface, genericos, c#-8.0

Tengo un ´switch´ el cual recibe un `object`. En caso de utilizar un `list` funciona correctamente, pero si utilizo un `Dictionary` no funciona.

```
object data = DataStructureFactory.Make();

switch (data)  
{
    case IEnumerable<IEntity> listStackOrQueue:
         // works
    case IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid,IEntity>> keyValuePair:
         // don't works
    case IDictionary<Guid,IEntity> dictionary:
         // don't works
    default:
         throw new InvalidCastException(
              "El tipo {0}, no pudo ser reconocido.", 
              data.GetType().Name);
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto recibo el siguiente error:

> El tipo Dictionary`2, no pudo ser reconocido.

Me he fijado de que la interfaz `IEnumerable` tiene el modificador **out** `IEnumerable<out T>`, por lo que, investigue sobre el asunto y encontré sobre [Variance in Generic Interfaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces). No sé si tenga algo que ver, pero aún no he resuelto el problema.

Comment: Diría que tienes que hacer el switch sobre el campo data.Values, que equivale a una List con los elementos del Dictionary. Entiendo que tienes una variable Dictionary<k,v> llamada data.

Comment: Que es `data`? no termino de entender ese switch

Comment: `data` es un `object` es decir que puede ser un `[List, Stack, Queue, Array, Vector, Dictionary, Tree, ...]`,

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar un "TypeOf"?

Comment: La pregunta es "C# 8 case no castea los Dictionary", necesito castear el `object` no comprobar el tipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final me he decidido por utilizar `decorator desing pattern` y modificar las estructuras de datos para que implementen `IEnumerable<T>`.

Pero encontré un **work around** creando mis propias interfaces utilizando
[Variance in Generic Interfaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces).

```
public interface INode<out T>
{
    bool HasPrevious { get; }
    bool HasNext { get; }
    T Previous { get; }
    T Current { get; }
    T Next { get; }
    int Count { get; }
}

public interface ITree<out T> where T : ITreeBranch
{
    T Container { get; }
    IEnumerable<ITreeBranch> this[int enumerator] { get; }
}

public interface IVarianceDictionary<out TKey, out TValue>
{
    IEnumerable<TKey> Keys { get; }
    IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get; }
}
```

En el `select case` simplemente hago el **castin** con las interfaces que cree.

```
object data = DataStructureFactory.Make();

switch (data)  
{
    case IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid,IEntity>> keyValuePair:
         // don't works
    case IDictionary<Guid,IEntity> dictionary:
         // don't works
    case IEnumerable<IEntity> listStackOrQueue:
         // works
    case IEnumerable<IEntity[]> array:
         // works
    case INode<IEntity> node:
         // works
    case ITree<IEntity> tree:
         // works
    case IVarianceDictionary<Guid,IEntity> varianceDictionary:
         // works
    default:
         throw new InvalidCastException(
              "El tipo {0}, no pudo ser reconocido.", 
              data.GetType().Name);
}
```

Por ultimo dejo el [repositorio](https://jerajo.visualstudio.com/_git/DataStructuresCSharp2019), por si quieren ver el código completo.

Answer (score 1):

Veo varias cosas en el código,

1. Terminas

> DataStructureFactory.Make()

con ":" en lugar de ";".

2. Los nombres de las variables dentro del switch (independiente del caso a evaluar) deben ser únicas. Tu estás utilizando `model` para todos los casos.
3. En el tercer caso, estás colocando como `expresión de tipo`una expresión que (Por derivación) ya tienes definida en el segundo caso. Es decir, `IDictionary<Guid,IEntity>` implementa `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid,IEntity>>`por lo que el `case`ya estaría contemplado en el segundo caso (Aquí salta error del compilador, porque no está permitido, pero no porque sea un error de casteo).
4. En el `default case`colocas una firma de `InvalidCastException`que no existe.

Como yo lo veo, tu código podría quedar así:

```
object data = DataStructureFactory.Make();

switch (data)  
{
    case IEnumerable<IEntity> modelListOfEntity:
         // ...
    case IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid,IEntity>> modelDictOfEntity:
         // ...
    default:
         throw new InvalidCastException($"El tipo {data.GetType().Name}, no pudo ser reconocido.");
}
```

Comment: Me he dado cuentan de que no es factible utilizar un `select case` voy a utilizar un `decorator` que implemente `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Estaría genial que, en caso de que puedas, compartieras el código para que otras personas puedan ver este enfoque que propones y quizas les sea de ayuda también.

Comment: deje el repositorio en mi respuesta.